# Angular 4 unit testing template parse errors:

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am getting the following error when I run angular unit test using Jasmine.

Error: Template parse errors:
Property binding cdkHeaderRowDef not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    
[ERROR ->]

```
<mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
[ERROR ->]<mat-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index; let isOdd = odd; let isEven ="): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TabledataComponent.html@57:4
```

Its looks like material design parsing error. Please suggest me what would be the issue?

Comment: Did you import the modules relative to the CDK table ?

Comment: Yes I have included the CDK table but still it shows the same error

Comment: Then could you show us the declaration of your testbed ?

Comment: Also, I don't know about your Material version, but now it's `matHeaderRowDef`, not `cdkHeaderRowDef`

Comment: Testbed declaration is :: beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TabledataComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule, HttpModule ],
      providers: [ TestService ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

Comment: What about you edit your question instead ?

Comment: And you didn't import the module ...

Comment: After changing cdk to 'mat' this error is being showing [ERROR ->]<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

Comment: **STOP. POSTING. CODE. IN. COMMENTS.** And you didn't import the table module, I gave you an asnwer, try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the table module into your testBed.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TabledataComponent],
    imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpModule, MatTableModule],
    providers: [RaindanceServiceService],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```